# Plotting scatter graph using matplotlib for y=0 and y=1 with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot a Scatter Graph using matplotlib where my x-axis and y-axis are two features X[0], X[1] and it should plot points with different colors where y=0 and y=1.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv('F:/ex2data2.txt', sep=",", header=None)
X=df.iloc[:, :2]
y=df.iloc[:, 2]

def plotData(X,y):
    fig=plt.figure()
    pos = y==1
    neg = y==0
    plt.plot(X[pos, 0], X[pos, 1], 'k*')
    plt.plot(X[neg, 0], X[neg, 1], 'ko')
    plt.show()

plotData(X,y)
```

The line "plt.plot(X[pos, 0], X[pos, 1], 'k*') and plt.plot(X[neg, 0], X[neg, 1], 'ko')" is showing error.
Can anyone help me with the reason?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select DataFrame by boolean mask and by column `0` or `1`:

```
X=df.iloc[:, :2]
y=df.iloc[:, 2]

def plotData(X,y):
    fig=plt.figure()
    pos = y==1
    neg = y==0
    plt.plot(X.loc[pos, 0], X.loc[pos, 1], 'k*')
    plt.plot(X.loc[neg, 0], X.loc[neg, 1], 'ko')
    plt.show()

plotData(X,y)
```

Or convert values of `Dataframe` and `Series` to numpy arrays:

```
X=df.iloc[:, :2].to_numpy()
y=df.iloc[:, 2].to_numpy()

#oldier pandas versions
#X=df.iloc[:, :2].values
#y=df.iloc[:, 2].values

def plotData(X,y):
    fig=plt.figure()
    pos = y==1
    neg = y==0
    plt.plot(X[pos, 0], X[pos, 1], 'k*')
    plt.plot(X[neg, 0], X[neg, 1], 'ko')
    plt.show()

plotData(X,y)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked @jezrael. So the X and y I was taking from data frame were still in data frame format or was it converted into some other data type like array?

Comment: @UmarMalik - It depends what need ;) But if use only `df.iloc[:, :2]` it return DataFrame, and `df.iloc[:, 2]` return `Series`.